# Can I determine if query does NOT find any children with values within a specified range?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can I somehow determine if no children at `ref` exist with vals between `-1` and `newTotal`?

Here's what I was hoping would work. The callback runs if children exist within the query.

```
ref.orderByValue().startAt(-1).endAt(newTotal).limitToLast(1).once("child_added", function(snap){

   /* Runs only when query yields a result */

   if (snap.exists()){
     ...
   } else {
     ...
   }

});
```

`newTotal` is 0 or any positive integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `child_` events will only fire when the relevant child exists/changes.

To detect when there are no children, you'll need to (also) listen for the `value` event:

```
var query = ref.orderByValue().startAt(-1).endAt(newTotal).limitToLast(1)

query.once("value", function(snapshot){
  if (snapshot.exists()){
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
      ..
    });
  } else {
     console.log('No child exists');
  }    
});
```