# Firebasedatabase - how to count child node

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase as a database. I would like to know how I can count the children of the father. what I'm trying to do is, if there are no childrens I want to show text view, but if there are children under the father I want to show a recycleview of all the children.
Each group saved under the user ID. Under the user id saved all the groups that the user has opened.
I have tried several things but still, haven't figure out how to do that.
Please take a look on the picture link, hope you understand.

[image: FirebaseDatabse Group node]

**EDIT:**

The code for the counting childrens

```
  refCountMembers.getReference(Params.GROUP_LISTS).child(currentUser.getUid()).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                long count = snapshot.getChildrenCount(); 
                if(snapshot.getChildrenCount() == 0) {
                    +"");                 
                    tvEmptyListGroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                }else{
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    tvEmptyListGroup.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Params.GROUP_LISTS).child(currentUser.getUid());
                    GroupsAdapter adapter = new GroupsAdapter(ref,getParentFragment(),progressBar);
                    rvGroup.setAdapter(adapter);
                    rvGroup.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
     }
   }
  }
```

I did it with childEventListener becuase i want to make sure when i delete a group and there are 0 groups so it will show the textview or if i'll add a group it should show the recyclerView.
childEventListener fires up evey time there is a change it the parent, right?

Comment: The solution will likely involve [`DataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getChildrenCount()). It's a bit hard to help beyond that without seeing your code that gets the parent node.

Comment: I added my code. is it good?

Comment: To detect if there are no children, you will either need to keep your own counter (increment in `onChildAdded`, decrement in `onChildRemoved`) or you will need an additional `ValueEventListener` on the same location. In the latter case, you can use `snapshot.getChildrenCount() == 0` or `!snapshot.exists()` to detect the absence of child node. Also see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39900082/can-i-determine-if-query-does-not-find-any-children-with-values-within-a-specifi/39900316#39900316 (for JavaScript, but the Android SDK works the same).

Comment: Thanks, it really helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Model Class as your group info.

```
public class Group {
    private String groupName;
    private String groupUID;
    private String ownerGroupUID;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Now get all group saved under a user Id.

```
    final List<Group> groupList = new ArrayList<>(); // list of groups
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference()
            .child("GroupLists")
            .child("dS...") // this is the id of user - over whose groups you want to iterate
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        Group group = snapshot.getValue(Group.class); // this is a group
                        groupList.add(group); // add to list
                    }

                    if (groupList.size()>0){
                        // Now display all groups in recycler view..

                    } else {
                        // Now display in textview that group list is empty

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

}
```